# Write to robot framework console from Python

Tags: python, console, robotframework

I am a newbie using python and I wanted to ask for your help in showing me how can I print messages from Python into robot framework console.

Comment: Haven't really tried anything yet. To be honest, since I am a newbie I have no slight clue on where to start from :)....

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We try to answer specific questions, rather than writing tutorials or writing code for you. I understand that sometimes it can be difficult to even tell where to start with a problem -- you might want to consider editing your question to ask for links to documentation or search terms you could use to learn more. (use the "edit" link under the question tags.)

Answer (score 29):

There are several ways for a python function to send information to the robot logs or to the console. These are all documented in the Robot framework user's guide, in the section titled [Logging information](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#logging-information).

The cleanest way is to use the [logging API](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-logging-apis), which gives specialized functions for various kinds of logging. For example, to send information to the console you would use `logger.console(message)`.

#### Using the logging API

Here is a library file that uses this method:

```
# ExampleKeywords.py
from robot.api import logger
def write_to_console(s):
    logger.console(s)
```

You can use this library in the following manner:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | ExampleKeywords.py

*** Test Cases ***
| Use a custom keyword to write to the console
| | Write to console | Hello, world
```

This will appear in the console only, and will not show up in the logs. If you want the information to show up in the logs you can use logger methods `info`, `warn`, `debug`, or `trace`. To log an error you would simply throw an exception.

#### Calling built-in keywords

There are other ways for your custom keywords to send information to the logs. For example, you can get a reference to the BuiltIn library, and directly call the [log](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log) or [log to console](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20To%20Console) keywords like this:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
def write_to_console(s):
    BuiltIn().log_to_console("Hello, world")
```

#### Using print statements

Finally, you can write information to the logs (but not only to the console) using print statements. You can prefix the string with `*<level>*` to affect the log level. For example, to print a warning you can do:

```
print "*WARN* Danger Will Robinson"
```

#### Summary

Using the API is arguably the best method to log information from your keywords. However, this is a fairly new API only available since Robot Framework 2.6, so if you are using an older version of Robot you may need to use one of the other techniques.

Answer (score 7):

What it sounds like you're asking for is a way to write a library such that your testcase can print to the console during test execution.

This is pretty easy, you can find it in the RF Manual under [Logging Information](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#logging-information).  The short version is you can log a "WARN" that will appear in both the log and on screen with a print statement, like so:

```
print "*WARN* This text will show up on the console."
```

Comment: This simple technique is great for running single-testcase from the command-line, since the yellow-colored `[WARN]` labels really stand out. But when ran batch/remotely (i.e. Jenkins), all the `[WARN]` messages are reproduced in a section at the top of the `log.html` file/page. This is a little distracting, although a benefit is that each line has a clickable link to drills down into the log context where it happened.

Answer (score 3):

This command can be used to print any message or content on robot console.

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
BuiltIn().log_to_console("Message that needs to be printed")
```