# Log dictionary to console in `robot framework`

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a dictionary like this

```
{ a:{red ,blue, green}, b: {head, eyes, nose} }
```

and I want to print this in the console formatted in a pretty way like this.

```
------------
a
------------
red
blue
green
-------------
b
-------------
head
eyes
nose
-------------
```

Since `robot framework` does not support nested loops, I find it difficult to do this. I want to handle this in the job console and not the `log.html`.

Comment: Yes. If I print anything in Python code, it gets printed in the log.html and not the console. Is there a way to override it?

Comment: Nested loops in Robot Framework are supported, through calling a keyword that holds the nested loop. A little less traditional then one would program in Python. The Robot Framework Userguide has a specific section on [Nested Loops](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops)

Answer (score 5):

This will print what you want to the [console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518298/write-to-robot-framework-console-from-python) with only one loop:

```
from robot.api import logger

d = { "a":{"red" ,"blue", "green"}, "b": {"head", "eyes", "nose"} }
divider = "------------"
s = []

for item in d:
    s.append(divider)
    s.append(item)
    s.append(divider)
    s.extend(d[item])

s = "\n".join(s)

logger.console(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although a Python solution is likely to give you a bit more flexibility with regards to formatting etc, the out-of-the-box keywords in Robot are sufficient to create the desired logic. See below for the code example and the output:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections    

*** Variables ***
@{a}    red     blue    green
@{b}    head    eyes    nose
&{DIC}    a=${a}    b=${b}


*** Test Cases ***
TC
    Log Structure    ${DIC}

*** Keywords ***
Log Structure
    [Arguments]    ${structure}
    Log To Console    \n
    Log To Console    ------------------------------

    # For Loops only work on Lists, so get all the keys from the Dictionary
    ${keys}     Get Dictionary Keys    ${structure}

    :FOR    ${item}    IN   @{keys}
    \    Log Many To Console    ${item}    ${structure["${item}"]}


Log Many To Console
    [Arguments]    ${name}    ${list}

    Log To Console    ${name}
    Log To Console    ------------------------------

    :FOR    ${item}    IN     @{list}
    \    Log To Console    ${item}

    Log To Console    ------------------------------
```

This then results in the following console output:

```
==============================================================================
ConsoleLog.ConsoleLog                                                         
==============================================================================
TC                                                                    

------------------------------
a
------------------------------
red
blue
green
------------------------------
b
------------------------------
head
eyes
nose
------------------------------
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConsoleLog.ConsoleLog                                                 | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
```